# Google adsense ads displaying ontop

Tags: adsense

I have just added a Google Adsense ad to my page. I have a navbar on my page that is fixed to the top of the screen. The adsense ad is inside a DIV that normally behaves normally and displays under the navbar, but once the ad is displayed the ad displays ontop of the navbar.
Navbar code:

```css
#navbar {
        position: fixed;
        width: 100%;
        height: 66px;
        background-color: #1C1C1C;
    }
```

```html
    <div id="navbar">
        <!-- Orange bar in Navbar-->
     <div id="topbar"></div>
     <div id="buttons">
      <!--Home button-->
      <a href="/"><p class="button">- Home</p></a>
      <!--Divider-->
      <div class="divider"></div>
      <!--Raffles Button-->
      <a href="raffles.php"><p class="button">Raffles</p></a>
      <!--Divider-->
      <div class="divider"></div>
      <!--Get tokens Button-->
      <a href="gettokens.php"><p class="dbutton">Get<br>Tokens</p></a>
            <!--Divider-->
            <div class="divider"></div>
            <!--Token lotto Button-->
            <a href="lotto.php"><p class="dbutton">Token<br>Lotto</p></a>
     </div>
        <div id="signin">
        </div>
     <div id="profile">
     </div>
</div>
```

Ad DIV:

```css
div#ad300x600 {
 margin-left: 50px;
 height: 600px;
 width: 300px;
 background-image: url("miscimg/YUADBLOCK.jpg");
 background-size: 0 0;
 float: left;
}
```

```html
<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<!-- csgohumblelargeskyscraper -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:inline-block;width:300px;height:600px"
     data-ad-client="ca-pub-xxx"
     data-ad-slot="xxx"></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
```

I have tried giving the Ad DIV a z-index: -100; and the Navbar a z-index: 1; but that hasn't helped. How can I make the ad display under the Nav bar. Also something that would be nice instead would be if the ad wouldn't move. But if I give it the position: fixed; tag it pops into the top right corner of the screen and stays there.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wts4Q.png

(The grey is the Navbar the white is the Ad)

Comment: Apolagies, I forgot to include those. I have now updated the post @JonKantner

Answer (score 0):

Seems that if I do an exaggerated amount of z-index like "99999999999" it works fine. Sorry to have posted this and figured out a solution myself.

Comment: You could also use `position: fixed; top: 80px;` for the `.adsbygoogle` class to keep the ad under the nav bar.